# Forecasting against multiple values in Python/ Spyder?

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, powerbi-desktop

i'm using this code but it's not working as i want. i have multiple columns e.g. "GL_Description", "Vendor", "Cost center"............"Amount" i want to display 1 year forecast of each GL_Decsription for e.g. when i select any GL_Description value in PowerBI Filter it display the forecasted value of selected GL Column. i'm working in Python script how can i do that I applied many logics but none of these are working, pls help me how can i modified this code in python.

Note:
below code is showing 1 year forecast but only one GL_Description value not for all.

```
 selected_product = dataset['GL_DESCRIPTION'].iloc[:].unique()

# Filter data for the selected product
filtered_data = dataset[dataset['GL_DESCRIPTION']==selected_product]

# Time series data preparation
time_series = pd.Series(filtered_data['AMOUNT'].values, index=filtered_data['CombinedDate'])
time_series.index = pd.to_datetime(time_series.index)  # Make sure the index is in datetime format

# Forecast using auto_arima from pmdarima
model = auto_arima(time_series)
forecast_result, conf_int = model.predict(n_periods=12, return_conf_int=True)

# Create a DataFrame with forecast results for the selected product
forecast_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Forecasted Date': pd.date_range(time_series.index[-1] + pd.DateOffset(1), periods=12, freq='MS'),
    'Item': [selected_product] * 12,
    'Company': [dataset['COMPANY_NAME'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'CostType': [dataset['COST_TYPE'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'CostCenterGroup': [dataset['COST_CENTER_GROUP'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'DocNo.': [dataset['DOCUMENT_NO'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'LongTxt.': [dataset['LONG_TEXT'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'ShortTxt.': [dataset['SHORT_TEXT'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'Vendor.': [dataset['VENDOR'].iloc[:]] * 12,
    'Forecast': forecast_result + np.random.normal(size=12)  # Adding random noise for demonstration
})

#save forecast_data date column into date type
forecast_data['Forecasted Date'] = pd.to_datetime(forecast_data['Forecasted Date'])
```